# How to create a repository that is pointed to some URL using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to Tortoise SVN, I have learnt to create a repository with a blank folder. However, it straight away created the repository using the local file path as its access. There is no option for me to create some URL that will be pointed to the repository so that I can access through browser. For example, https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/Desktop/Repository. I want to use the URL to see through what is inside the Repository folder. Is that possible? How can I set some URL that will retrieve the file inside the repository folder?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN doesn't include an HTTP server.

If you chose to install the Subversion binaries then you'll have [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) around, which allows remote access but, again, not specifically HTTP:

> The svnserve program is a lightweight server, capable of speaking to clients over TCP/IP using a **custom, stateful protocol**. Clients contact an svnserve server by using URLs that begin with the svn:// or svn+ssh:// scheme

I presume it's [Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) what you're looking for but it isn't bundled in TortoiseSVN.

Last but not least, access to repositories is independent from repository creation. One same repository can be used through any of the different protocols.